# How can I display a "loading" message in an MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, appharbor

I have an MVC application I'm hosting on AppHarbor that takes 20 seconds or so to start up.  Since I can't control the timeout period on AppHarbor, any user that visits the application gets a blank screen while resources spool up.

I'd like to at least show the user *something* other than a blank page while resources are being loaded.

I've tried adding an index.html page with a redirect, but I only want that page to appear when the application first fires up.

Comment: you can use javascript for that. I'm using one myself which was very easy to install, but I can't remember where I got it from...

Comment: @LiranBo any chance you can post a snippet of the js here?   Downvoting aside, you didn't feel it was a dumb question.  Much obliged if you can help point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/display-loading-image-while-page-loads/), it's not the one I currently use (couldn't find it online), but it seems easy enough to use.

Since you have a very long load at the start, you can use this:

```
//hide after page load completed
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.loader').css("display", "none");
});
```

Other then that just follow their explanation there, if you have any questions about it, I'll try and help more.